How to publish the changed items during the Data Exchange import process?
We would like to combine all the modified/created/deleted items during the DataExchange import process and finally would like to publish all the combined items to all the languages, all the publishing targets.
Please provide some insights on this.

DataExchange Framework usually points to a folder under which items are modified/created/deleted. I assume a pipeline step at the end of pipeline shall work for you which shall publish the folder with subitems in all languages and to all publishing targets. Is this what you are looking for?

I implemented the indexing process in my project like below.

Using insert options create a new item of template “Write to Index” and name it “Write to Index”.

Choose the Parent item to index i.e. the root of the new items. and Endpoint to i.e. Sitecore Database Endpoint.


Refer to my blog where I described the step-by-step process to setup a simple data exchange framework.
https://sbhatiablogs.wordpress.com/2019/11/21/a-simple-data-exchange-framework-setup/
Hope this helps.

Thanks Sumit. I don't see the publishing related logic in the article. Please help me on that.

Check Write to Index step 20
